# How to set the condition on Cursor

Tags: android-ndk

I want to set the condition on the Cursor that if certain data not found in the database return String NOT FOUND.

```
static class NoteHolder {
    private TextView noteText = null;

    NoteHolder(View row) {
        noteText = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.notecontent);

    }

    void populateFrom(Cursor c, NoteHelper helper) {
        noteText.setText(helper.getAnswer(c));

    }

}
```

MY Database Helper Code Is

```
    public Cursor getAll() {
        return (getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(
                "SELECT _id,Answer From Q_A Where Answer like '%"
                        + searchcontent + "%'", null));
    }

    public String getAnswer(Cursor c) {

        return (c.getString(1));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://commonsware.com/warescription have a brilliant collection of books (they're not free, but the price is VERY good, plus you get free updates!)

Answer (score 2):

Very Good Tutorial For Start Database Programming...

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Answer (score 0):

http://books.google.com/books?id=5VTBuvfZDyoC&pg=PA35&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false

This is NOT a complete book. However, there is more than enough information here for you to learn quite a bit from the ~150 pages provided. It leaves out some very basic details and it also leaves out some explanations of core concepts, but it can still be a great (free) resource. I'd recommend buying the actual book, as it has helped me tremendously due to the way it presents the information. I suck at programming so I need it presented in an easy to understand way. You can still learn a significant amount with preview available here though.

edit: For a tutorial to get you going, try: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html